# Power 2 120VAC transformers with 220vac

Tags: transformer, ac, series

In reference to the following.

([Connecting the primaries of two 110V transformers in series across 220V](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/413977/connecting-the-primaries-of-two-110v-transformers-in-series-across-220v/646269?noredirect=1#comment1714415_646269))

Putting 2 identical 120 VAC transformers in series in US. Having 2 Hot's and 1 Neutral if I wire these as the above states I'm still left with the neutral. Can someone help me understand this. My home wiring is old meaning the ground and neutral are 1 in the same.

I'm also considering ballasting this arrangement. Anyone willing to help guide me?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What about connecting each `120 VAC transformer` to `Hot and Neutral` independently?

Comment: US is "split-phase." My house is 50+ yrs old and does NOT have separate ground and neutral bar in the entrance panel. If you wire the two transformers without using neutral, they will be okay *until* you load one secondary and not the other. If you have access to both hots (L1 & L2) and neutral at the same location for both transformers, then wire one of them between L1 and neutral and the other one between L2 and neutral. If they are both equally *resistively* loaded, then neutral won't have much current on it. Which is fine. But if only one is being used, then neutral is needed. So use it.

Comment: That's how I have them wired now Jonk. I'm getting a some kind of feedback. Possible ground loop?

Answer (score 0):

this could work if you wire the secondaries of the two transformwers in series or in parallel, otherwise no, the voltage won't balance correctly with an unbalanced load.

Comment: Yes, I planned on wiring secondaries in series. Shorting 1 to ground of other. This still leaves the neutral. I think I'll stick with separate hots, L1+N and L2+N. Should I ground to each other or separate earth grnds?

Comment: the question you linked to was completely different to yours. leave the neutral unconnected.